# Is an OBL argument in complement or adjunct position?

Tags: syntax-trees, adjuncts, constituents, argument

My syntax lecture materials on Arguementhood vs Adjuncthood explain that one difference between arguments and adjuncts lies in the participation in alternations: only arguments participate in alternations. ADJ constituents -in general- get neither promoted nor demoted. Take for examples:

1. a. The room swarmed with people (oblique)

   b. People swarmed the room
2. a. Ian cleaned with a cloth (instrument)

   b. *A cloth cleaned

In example 1a), should the PP argument *with people* be placed in adjunct or complement position when drawing a constituent tree for 1a)?

Many thanks to the friendly linguists on this site who are obliged to help with my questions!

Comment: I'd say that it's a complement in 1a since it's licensed by "swarmed". In 2a the more salient interpretation is comitative adjunct.